# Updating Google Maps steals focus from form elements

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I have a google maps embed on my site, which I'd like to update with the user's current location. It's non-interactive but when I change the coordinates like this, where `pos` is a coordinates object:

```js
map.setCenter(pos);
```

The map will steal focus from any other form elements on the page. Eg: If I have a text field focused and am typing, and the location updates the text field will lose focus and I'll be typing into nothing.

Is there a good way to fix this? I have no clue what I could do.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I realized I was calling `mapwindow.open(map)` on a window object which was stealing focus. Lesson learned, setting the map center doesn't steal focus, opening an attachment on the map does.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Sometimes all you need is to articulate the problem you're facing to see what you're doing wrong. Gotta love programming ;)

Comment: @LukePoirrier Totally! Too often I ask a question and then realize the answer only after stepping away or saying/typing it out!